# How to hash a field in XML using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

There is a XML from that I am constructing an another XML using XSLT. I want some fields to have Hashed Value rather than actual value. Meaning I should know when data is changed but I don't want to know the data due to some security reasons.

```
<xsl:template name="sensitiveDataTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="sensitiveData"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test="$sensitiveData!=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="'XXXXXX'"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

For now I am just replacing data with XXXXX but I need some hashed value here.

Comment: As for pure XSLT/XPath, there is the `generate-id()` function you can call on any input node which gives you an ID hash. But I guess you are looking for a particular algorithm, you will need to check whether your used XSLT processor allows calling into a programming platform like .NET or Java where your hash algorithm is already implemented.

Comment: @MartinHonnen for same string value does generate-id() returns same ID hash? If yes then generate-id() can solve my problem.

Comment: generate-id works one nodes not on strings but for the same node during a single run of an XSLT stylesheet it returns the same id. But of course if you combine it with grouping e.g. Muenchian grouping in XSLT 1 you can create the same "hash" value by always creating the generated id for the first item in a group of nodes with the same value, see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWVf/2 for an example which does that.

Comment: What XSLT engine are you using? Does it need to use a particular hashing algorithm (sha265, sha1, md5), or just obfuscated? Do you need it to be a pure XSLT solution, or might you consider calling either an extension function, or even a web service i.e. `document(concat("http://some.hashing.service?valueToHash=", $val)`

Comment: @MadsHansen I am using PHP, and now I have a solution through PHP. Thanks

Comment: Can't we use some self generated UUID or long timestamp, that will be unique every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out a solution a while back, which is similar to the answer given above.

I simply called PHP function to use SHA1 hashing.
XSL :

```
<xsl:template name="sensitiveDataTemplate">
<xsl:param name="sensitiveData"></xsl:param>
<xsl:if test="$sensitiveData!=''">
    <xsl:value-of select="php:function('sha1', substring($sensitiveData,1, string-length($sensitiveData)))"></xsl:value-of>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

PHP:

```
$proc->registerPHPFunctions('sha1');
```

Answer (score 1):

For generating the hash value you may register the custom functions.

Refer to the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.registerphpfunctions.php) on how to register custom php function in xlst processor.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl">
 <xsl:template name="sensitiveDataTemplate">
    <xsl:param name="sensitiveData"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:if test="$sensitiveData!=''">
        <xsl:value-of select="'php:some_hash_fun()'"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

function some_hash_fun( )
{
    return "XXXX"; // hash value
}
$xmldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xml);
$xsldoc = DOMDocument::loadXML($xsl);

$proc = new XSLTProcessor();
$proc->registerPHPFunctions();  // can be either a string (a function name) or an array of functions.
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsldoc);
echo $proc->transformToXML($xmldoc);
```

Hope it helps.